# How to train in Keras a nn4.small2 model for face recognition system using a triplet loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, face-recognition

I am trying to train an nn4.small2 model for face recognition app, but I am not sure how to do it right using triplet loss function.

I have found a lot of documentation about this, the most relevant is here: https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/app/1A_089.pdf.
So, I am going to reproduce it with my dataset.

Have anyone done that before and would like to share his/her experience with me?